# Python chat error

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on a chat client, and this is my code:

```
import sys
import socket
import select


def run():

    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 8008
    buffer = 4096

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(5)

    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print("Connection failed.")
        #exit

    print("Connected to " + host)
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()

    while True:
        sockets = [sys.stdin, s]
        ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(sockets, [], [])

        for sock in ready_to_read:
            if sock == s:
                data = sock.recv(buffer)
                if not data:
                    print("Disconnected.")
                    #exit
                else:
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

But when I run it (the server is running aswell, let me know if you need the code) it gives me this error:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Dev/Python/Chat/Client/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
Connected to 127.0.0.1
  File "C:/Dev/Python/Chat/Client/main.py", line 44, in <module>
[Me]     sys.exit(run())
  File "C:/Dev/Python/Chat/Client/main.py", line 26, in run
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(sockets, [], [])
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Process finished with exit code 1
```

By the way, I followed an old Python 2 tutorial to make this (http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php) so it may have something to do with that.

Comment: I guess sys.stdin is not a socket in windows and can't be "selected" ?

Comment: I think this error is connected with select() implementation in Windows. Check here [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) - Empty sequences are allowed, but acceptance of three empty sequences is platform-dependent. (It is known to work on Unix but not on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is old but the page it links to came up first in my search for a python chat server. As I needed some working code to play with I thought others might appreciate an updated chat_client.py for use with the very simple server at http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php*

The error is because `sys.stdin` is not a socket on Windows. This reduces the usefulness of `select` so we are forced to use threads.

Here is a minimal correct client implementation, for Windows:

## chat_client.py

```
import sys
import socket
import select
from threading import Thread

def receive(s):
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            ready = select.select([s], [], [])
            if ready[0]:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    print '\nDisconnected from chat server'
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    # print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] ')
                    sys.stdout.flush()
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break


def chat_client2():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print 'Usage : python chat_client.py hostname port'
        sys.exit()

    host = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)

    # connect to remote host
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
    except:
        print 'Unable to connect'
        sys.exit()

    print 'Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages'
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] ')
    sys.stdout.flush()

    receive_thread = Thread(target=receive, args=(s,))
    receive_thread.daemon = True
    receive_thread.start()

    while 1:
        # user entered a message
        msg = sys.stdin.readline()
        s.send(msg)
        sys.stdout.write('[Me] ')
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(chat_client2())
```